# Npm run dev not working due to a lack of a script but the script seems to be there

Tags: node.js, npm

I've been trying to run the frontend of the project I've been working on since it was left to me by a former coworker, I installed node as the README he left suggested but other than saying "npm run dev" and "go to localhost:3000" there isn't any other info.

These are the logs I'm getting after inputting "npm run dev" and "npm run pidelo-app@0.1.0 dev" as the console suggested. Am I missing a dependency? or is the script missing altogether? I don't have much experience with JS so this might be a common issue.

```
(base) Grims-Macbook:Frontend grimidk$ npm run dev

> pidelo-app@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

sh: next: command not found
```

```
(base) Grims-Macbook:Frontend grimidk$ npm run pidelo-app@0.1.0 dev
npm ERR! Missing script: "pidelo-app@0.1.0"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/grimidk/.npm/_logs/2023-12-22T15_26_08_439Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe You haven't installed the dependencies,
try running this in terminal -

```
npm install
```

It will install all dependencies required from the package.json

and after then use -

```
npm run dev
```

[Make sure you are in the same folder as your app]

Localhost 3000 is not necessary, after running the previous script you will get the info of where exactly your server is running and you can just go to

```
http://localhost:{PORT_NUMBER}
```

If all this still does not work, try installing Node.js again in your terminal by going to this website - https://nodejs.org/en

It is also possible that your code editor does not have permission to run commands so just open your PC Command prompt and go to the location and try again.

Comment: npm install did not work at first but I added the --force tag and it did work afterwards but it created some vulnerabilities, is that normal, or should I roll back the folder? The localhost did launch successfully.

Comment: It means that the project is either using very old versions of some libraries or some vulnerable third-party libraries. Normal vulnerabilities are fine but if the risk is very high, you should try reaching out to that co-worker since I have no details regarding what you are facing. If my solution helped you, consider accepting it as a solution.